# Inserting values in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On completion of a form I am creating a PDF and storing a few values of a form to a table. I would like to store the form values to a separate table. I am having trouble getting the code to store to both tables. This is my working code without adding the second SQL query:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$errors = array(); 
include('connect.php'); 

//if($_POST['email'] == ''){
//    $errors[]= 'Email cannot be empty';  
//}


if( count($errors) === 0 ) 
{
    $description = pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);  
    $filename = date('Ymdhis').".pdf"; 
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO documents (id, userid, description, name, date) VALUES (NULL, {$_SESSION['id']}, '{$description}' ,'{$filename}', NOW())"; 
     $success = mysql_query($sql);    

    include('../MPDF/mpdf.php'); 
    ob_start(); 
    include('../documents/siteSubmit.php');
    $html = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    ob_end_flush(); 

    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $folder = "../userDocuments/{$_SESSION['username']}"; 
    if(!is_dir($folder))
    {
        mkdir($folder, 0755, true);  
    } 
    $mpdf->writeHTML($html); 
    $mpdf->Output('../userDocuments/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/'.$filename); 
    echo json_encode(array('succes' => true)); 
}
else 
{
    echo json_encode(array('errors' => $errors)); 
}
```

and this is the values I would like to add to the other table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sitesubmit (first_name, last_name, email, telephone, truck_number, truck_mileage, carrier, site_number, lat, longitude, comments, job_completion) VALUES ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'telephone', 'truck_number', 'truck_mileage', 'carrier', 'site_number', 'lat', 'longitude ', 'comments')"; 

$success = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use this query but with different name. like that

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO documents (id, userid, description, name, date) VALUES (NULL, {$_SESSION['id']}, '{$description}' ,'{$filename}', NOW())"; 
  $success = mysql_query($sql);  
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO sitesubmit (first_name, last_name, email, telephone, truck_number, truck_mileage, carrier, site_number, lat, longitude, comments, job_completion) VALUES ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'telephone', 'truck_number', 'truck_mileage', 'carrier', 'site_number', 'lat', 'longitude ', 'comments','job_completion')"; 

 $success2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

EDIT:

the second query you are missing a value for `job_completion` , so this query will fail.

you have to make the value of that column.

Comment: thats not working. When I do it like this it just adds to the first table and ignores the second.

Comment: @NichoDiaz it will work , have you tried it? note that i have changed the names of queries .

Comment: yes I tried it and I tried it again with your code to make sure I was not messing up. still does not work. I dont know what I am missing here.

Comment: and try again my code , i edited and added a value for `job_completion`

Comment: ok thanks man! it entered it in the database! great! the only problem is it entered the acctual values we typed in the database instead of grabbing the values entered in to the input fields of the form.... each value is the same as the name='telephone' on form... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: dude , you inserted normal strings, in your case you have to insert the variables as you done in your first query. i dont know what variavles you have, but this is your work.